# MongoDB sort by join result with aggregate lookup

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections `user` and `post`

```
> db.user.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1473bc1b48d9309580a9de"),
    "user_id" : NumberLong(1),
    "region" : "US",
    "is_join" : true
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1473bc1b48d9309580a9df"),
    "user_id" : NumberLong(2),
    "region" : "KR",
    "is_join" : true
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1473bc1b48d9309580a9e0"),
    "user_id" : NumberLong(3),
    "region" : "US",
    "is_join" : true
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1473bc1b48d9309580a9e1"),
    "user_id" : NumberLong(4),
    "region" : "US",
    "is_join" : true
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1487fc1b48d9321ff5dc1f"),
    "user_id" : NumberLong(5),
    "region" : "US",
    "is_join" : true
}
```

```
> db.post.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1473bc1b48d9309580a9e2"),
    "post_id" : NumberLong(1),
    "user_id" : NumberLong(3),
    "body" : "hi"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1473bc1b48d9309580a9e3"),
    "post_id" : NumberLong(2),
    "user_id" : NumberLong(1),
    "body" : "hello"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1473bc1b48d9309580a9e4"),
    "post_id" : NumberLong(3),
    "user_id" : NumberLong(2),
    "body" : "go"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1473bc1b48d9309580a9e5"),
    "post_id" : NumberLong(4),
    "user_id" : NumberLong(4),
    "body" : "python"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d14941b1b48d93314907345"),
    "post_id" : NumberLong(5),
    "user_id" : NumberLong(1),
    "body" : "aa"
}
```

I want to join via mongo aggregate lookup operation.

So I made query like this.

```
db.user.aggregate([
    {
        '$match': {
            'region': 'US',
        }
    },
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'post',
            'localField': 'user_id',
            'foreignField': 'user_id',
            'as': 'user'
        }
    },
    {
        '$project': {
            '_id': 0,
            'user.post_id': 1
        }
    }
])
```

**Result**

```
{ "user" : [ { "post_id" : NumberLong(2) }, { "post_id" : NumberLong(5) } ] }
{ "user" : [ { "post_id" : NumberLong(1) } ] }
{ "user" : [ { "post_id" : NumberLong(4) } ] }
{ "user" : [ ] }
```

As you know that `post_id` is unordered.

But I want to sort it descending.

**Desired result**

```
{ "user" : [ { "post_id" : NumberLong(1) } ] }
{ "user" : [ { "post_id" : NumberLong(2) } ] }
{ "user" : [ { "post_id" : NumberLong(4) } ] }
{ "user" : [ { "post_id" : NumberLong(5) } ] }
```

**Even Better**

`{ "user" : [ 1, 2, 4, 5 }] }`

How can I modify aggregate query?

Thanks.

Comment: will there be only one `post_id` in each user? Or if multiple, how should the sorting be done?

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti No each user has multiple `post_id`. But regardless of that, I have to sort by all of post_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do following to get what you want:

1) `$unwind` the user array

2) use `$sort` to sort all documents with `post_id`

3) use `$group` as the next stage in your aggregation query, and push `user.post_id` to form one sorted `user` array from all the docs:

```
db.user.aggregate([
    {
        '$match': {
            'region': 'US',
        }
    },
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'post',
            'localField': 'user_id',
            'foreignField': 'user_id',
            'as': 'user'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind : {
            path : "$user",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays : true
        }
    },
    {
        $sort : {
            'user.post_id' : 1
        }
    },
    {
        $group : {
            _id  : null,
            user : {
                $push : "$user.post_id"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Read more about [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) , [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind) and [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group) for more information.

Comment: If each user has multiple post, it doesn't sort correctly.

Comment: so you want the post_id array sorted as well as the result of aggregation sorted, right? Can you show an example what you want if there are multiple post_id in a user doc?

Comment: Right. Exactly, order all documents by `post_id`.

Comment: throw `path option to $unwind stage should be prefixed with a '$': user"` errors.

Comment: add `$` to user, then query works. But it doent's sort yet. It seems just sort with first element of array.

Comment: It seems im misunderstanding the original question, can you give an example showing exactly what you want in case of multiple post_id?

Comment: i have edited my answer again to give the desired result you want. Please have a look'

Comment: It returns `{ "user" : [ ] }` LOL

Comment: You wont need $project stage, after the updated $group stage, i have edited the answer

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for detailed explanation :)